# Is it possible to make UNIX FTP client and CentOS VSFTPD server working together?

Tags: unix, centos, ftp, aix, vsftpd

I have a UNIX bull AIX client with ftp installed and a CentOS 6.2 server with vsftpd installed.

Can the client connect to the server ? Cause it seems that the vsftpd server is refusing all connections from that client.
I'm wondering if the OS system difference is disabling the connection cause file systems are too much different!
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vsftp must be told to

- accept unecrypted protocol,
- accept connexion on port 21,20

this is done in vsftpd.conf.

```
ssl_enable=no
connect_from_port_20=yes
userlist_enable=no
```

Comment: How is it done in `vsftpd.conf` ?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between client and server OS is of no importance.

client and server don't care about the filesystem which the other uses, they only use the FTP protocol.

Your problems must have another reason.